# Why is JQuery adding a style to my appended list item?

Tags: jquery

I'm using JQuery to drag items from one list and drop them onto another.

Once the item is dropped it is removed from its original list and appended to its destination list.

I've used the code below and it seems to perform perfectly fine when inspecting the DOM, however it displays incorrectly on the page. Usually outside of the list and to the top right.

My first guess is that this was a CSS issue, however the problem persists even after removing all stylesheets.

Closer inspection in the Chrome inspector reveals that an inline style is added to each list item.I'm not sure where its coming from.

Here's my code.

```
        $(function() {

    $( ".drag" ).draggable();

    $( ".drop" ).each(function (index){

        var title = $(this).attr('title');

        $(this).droppable({      
           accept:  title,
           activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
           hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
           drop: function( event, ui ) {

           ui.draggable.remove();
           $(this).append(ui.draggable);
           }
          }); 
    });
 });
</script>




<ul>
<li class="drag RED">RED</li>
<li class="drag BLUE">BLUE</li>
</ul>

<ul class="drop" title=".RED">
<li>Stuff</li>  
</ul>

<ul class="drop" title=".BLUE">
<li>Stuff</li>      
</ul>
```

Comment: you can use jsfiddle, to show this as demonstration.

Comment: what style was added wrong? did the color change from yellow to pink? what?! what are you expecting, and what is happening?

Comment: @Reigel I'm expecting the list item which is dragged to be inserted into the list that it is dragged to. The DOM inspector shows that this is occuring, but the list item appears outside of the list ie in the wrong position.

Comment: Also, I changed the object to be appended from ui.draggable to a string and that seems to work perfectly fine without any position errors. The problem seems to be ui.draggable

Comment: can you not fix it with css? Also, try to check using firebug( or chrome equivalent ) if the elements has some style attribute applied to it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean **style** like

```
position: relative; left: 151px; top: 32px;
```

if so, this is from jquery UI plugin, which tell where is your droped element, relative to parent.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem. I have no styles defined. I modified the script to remove all titles and classes however the position problem remains.

Comment: @matt dont you have style for RED,BLUE

Comment: `My first guess is that this was a CSS issue, however the problem persists even after removing all stylesheets.` , clearly from the OP :)

Comment: @Reigel there is nothing wrong with that , only i m saying , if further element is created in drop area using the class name.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this behaviour when working with some basic HTML and the Draggable jQuery library. Click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vRhnY/) for a JSFiddle replicating the issue.

I could only solve this by simply utilising jQuery's css() function to manually set the values to zero. e.g.

```
$(ui.draggable).css({'left': '0', 'top': '0'});
```

I appreciate you ask WHY which is a good question and one I can't answer but I thought it would be worthwhile to assist anyone who reaches this page with the same problem.